# Django - AttributeError at /prescription/ 'PrescriptionView' object has no attribute 'object_list'

Tags: python, django

I'm using an ajax post call to send an array of data to my view as follows:

```
class PrescriptionView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'meds/prescription.html'
    context_object_name = 'meds'
    model = Medicament

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        selected_ids = request.POST.getlist('selected[]')
        context = {'meds': Medicament.objects.filter(id__in=selected_ids)}
        return super(PrescriptionView, self).render_to_response(context)
```

As you can see my view is a ListView, all I want is to list those objects with the ids from the selected_ids which is `Medicament.objects.filter(id__in=selected_ids)` but for some reason I keep getting the following error:

```
AttributeError at /prescription/
'PrescriptionView' object has no attribute 'object_list'

Traceback:  

File "/home/nids/cabin/dentist/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/nids/cabin/dentist/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/nids/cabin/dentist/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/nids/cabin/dentist/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/nids/cabin/meds/views.py" in post
  38.         return super(PrescriptionView, self).render_to_response(context)

File "/home/nids/cabin/dentist/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in render_to_response
  132.             template=self.get_template_names(),

File "/home/nids/cabin/dentist/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py" in get_template_names
  200.         if hasattr(self.object_list, 'model'):

Exception Type: AttributeError at /prescription/
Exception Value: 'PrescriptionView' object has no attribute 'object_list'
```

**Edit**

Ajax call:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $( "#continue" ).click(function() {
            var selected = $("#meds").bootgrid("getSelectedRows");
            console.log(selected);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{% url 'meds:prescription' %}",
                data: {selected:'selected' , csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}"},
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Note: selected is an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once, I have used the following pattern while sending array of data:

```
var roles = data_selected();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/get_roles/',
    data: {'roles[]': roles},
   });
 });
```

And,in the django view, I

```
 def get_roles(request):
     roles = request.POST.getlist('roles[]')
     ....
```

Can you share you ajax call? I think the data might be messed while sending?

Handing post request :

```
def post(self, request, **kwargs):
      selected_ids = request.POST.getlist('selected[]')
      meds = self.get_queryset().filter(id__in=selected_ids)
      return render(request, self.template_name, {'meds': meds })
```

Comment: I just added it to the post

Comment: Looking at the documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#making-friendly-template-contexts, I didn't see any error. But, I would like to see how you are rendering your list. You are looping over 'meds' in the template, right?

Comment: I have modified the above answer with the handling post request: 
```def post(self, request, **kwargs):
      selected_ids = request.POST.getlist('selected[]')
      meds = self.get_queryset().filter(id__in=selected_ids)
      return render(request, self.template_name, {'meds': meds })```

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem! but how come I'm not redirected to the PrescriptionView template with the according 'meds'?

Comment: I didn't get your message. You mean the list is not displayed?

Comment: It just stays in the same page that I get the elements from, I don't get redirected to the one where the list is supposed to be displayed